# Grails Criteria - multiple functions on same field

Tags: mysql, grails, hql, criteria

I know I can use a mysql function in Criteria as follows:

```
Number rating = Book.createCriteria().get
      eq("author", author)
      projections {
          max rating
      }
}
```

to execute the equivalent of

```
select max(rating) from book where author = 'authors name';
```

But if this rating can be positive or negative, and I want the absolute maximum, is it possible to execute the following in Criteria:

```
select max(Abs(rating)) from book where author = 'authors name'
```

Maybe I need to revert to HQL but just wanted to see if this was something I could do first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd rewrite it as HQL

```
def result = Book.executeQuery(
    "select max(abs(rating)) from Book where author = :author", [author: author])
```

You can use SQL in the predicates of a criteria query via `sqlRestriction`, but I don't think it's possible to use them in `projections`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest way would be to add a formula to the `Book` class:

```
class Book {
    Integer rating
    Integer absRating
    ...

    static mapping = {
        absRating formula: 'ABS(RATING)'
    }
}
```

And then use `absRating` within your criteria:

```
Number rating = Book.createCriteria().get
      eq("author", author)
      projections {
          max absRating
      }
}
```

Link: [Derived Properties](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties)

Comment: Probable a bit overkill for me to edit the domain object as I only need to use this once in the entire application, I guess I need to use HQL if not possible.

Comment: True, it's a judgement call.  Personally, I think I would use it because I much prefer the `createCriteria` syntax over HQL but I know it ends up with the same generated SQL so it's an irrational dislike.

Answer (score 0):

Or in plain SQL:

```
def rating = new groovy.sql.Sql(datasource).firstRow("select max(Abs(rating)) rating from book where author = ${author.name}")?.rating
```

Comment: Thanks @defectus but as mentioned in the question, was looking to see if there was a solution using Criteria before reverting to HQL.

Comment: I know I just tried to be a bit funny. But if all you have is a hammer (or `Hibernate`), everything looks like a nail (or `Criteria`) :-)